# How to fix Flink 'error: cannot infer type arguments for FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>'

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm following examples of using Flink with Kafka.  I only find results like [this page](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-flink-data-pipeline) which don't compile correctly and give strage, difficult to lookup error messages.

Basically, when I try to compile this snippet, I get the error:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.DeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer011;

import java.util.Properties;

public final class Main {

    public static FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> createStringConsumerForTopic(
            String topic, String kafkaAddress, String kafkaGroup ) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
        props.setProperty("group.id",kafkaGroup);
        FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> consumer =
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>(topic, new SimpleStringSchema(),props);

        return consumer;
    }
}
```

Here's my dependencies and such in a `build.gradle` file:

```
group 'myapp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  ecj 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.6.1'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java_2.11', version: '1.2.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: '1.5.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-clients_2.11', version: '1.5.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-avro', version: '1.8.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-core', version: '1.5.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11', version: '1.5.0'

  compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: '1.1.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '1.1.0'

  compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
}
```

Here's the error when using a build tool to run the code:

```sh
$ gradle build
> Task :compileJava FAILED
/Users/john/dev/john/flink-example/src/main/java/com/company/opi/flinkexample/Main.java:55: error: cannot infer type arguments for FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>(topic, new SimpleStringSchema(),props);
                ^
Note: /Users/john/dev/john/flink-example/src/main/java/com/company/opi/flinkexample/EnvironmentConfig.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Here's a link to his [source code](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/05e1700fb76cb7e4c373f8cc66269d16d05885b6/libraries-data/src/main/java/com/baeldung/flink/connector/Consumers.java#L12-L21).

Comment: I looked up the flink source code and it looks like this should compile. Can you try running `gradle clean build` instead? Also, make sure that all of your dependencies are running the latest version.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob, it was in fact a versioning issue.  I didn't understand all the version numbers (scala version vs library version vs that other version for connector that was for the kafka version).  I can't upvote, but David's answer resolved my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem: all of the flink libraries you use should have the same version number -- you appear to be mixing versions 1.2.0, 1.5.0, and 1.8.0. 
Below are the updated dependencies and source code that will compile correctly.

(build.gradle)

```
group 'myapp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java_2.11', version: '1.8.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: '1.8.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-clients_2.11', version: '1.8.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-avro', version: '1.8.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-core', version: '1.8.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka_2.12', version: '1.8.0'

  compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
}
```

(workingCode.java)

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import java.util.Properties;

public final class Main {

    public static FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> createStringConsumerForTopic(
            String topic, String kafkaAddress, String kafkaGroup ) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
        props.setProperty("group.id",kafkaGroup);
        FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> consumer =
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic, new SimpleStringSchema(),props);

        return consumer;
    }
}
```

Also, but unrelated to the compile error, since you are using Kafka 1.1, you might as well use a more up-to-date version of Flink's Kafka connector, rather than the one intended for Kafka 0.11. FlinkKafkaConsumer (the class with no version number in its name) is the appropriate connector for Kafka 1.0.0 and later.